Add job id to each log message slf4j logback
This is a big web server that uses Logback for logging.
I want to add an identifier for each web request (e.g., job id) and log messages with this job id according to the request that created it.
This is a multi-threaded system and the initial web request thread can be split into several other threads, but they all need to know the initial job id.
Are there any best practices for implementing this? So that I don't have to manually pass this ID in each log message like
log.info("{} some message without parameter", jobId);
log.debug("{} another debug message with parameter {}", jobId, requiredParameter);

Ideally, it would be best to add this job id at the LayoutPattern level,
<property name="MY_LOG_PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %Х{jobid} ..."/>

but how can I make the logger aware of which web request triggered it?

To add an identifier for each web request (e.g., job ID) and log messages with this job ID in a multi-threaded web server using Logback, you can utilize Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC). MDC allows you to store contextual information and include it in your log messages automatically, without manually passing the ID in each log statement.

Configure Logback Pattern to Include MDC


Set MDC in the Request Entry Point
public class MDCFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Generate or get the job ID
        String jobId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        MDC.put("jobId", jobId);
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            MDC.remove("jobId");
        }
    }
}


Ensure jobId is Propagated in Multi-threaded Environments
  public class Example {
         private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
         public void processRequest() {
             Map<String, String> contextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
             executorService.submit(() -> {
                 if (contextMap != null) {
                     MDC.setContextMap(contextMap);
                 }
                 try {
                     // Perform task in the new thread
                     // Log messages will automatically include jobId
                     // log.info("Processing task in a new thread");
                 } finally {
                     MDC.clear();
                 }
             });
         }
     }




You can add your data to a thread-specific Map using ThreadContext:
ThreadContext.put("jobId", jobId);

and then reference that key in your logging layout (like you already suggested in the question):
"%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %Х{jobId}"

This way you don't have to pass that value to log.info/debug/... as log4j pulls them out of the ThreadContext (of which each Thread has its own instance).
For multiple values in the ThreadContext it might be easier to just print all of them using %X (without a key). For more details, look at this page.
